# Merge a property with its key in one index of array

Tags: javascript

i have an object in json format and i want to make an array of the both key and its property in one index.

Now the object looks like this:

```
currencies:{

AED: "United Arab Emirates Dirham"
ALL: "Albanian Lek"
AMD: "Armenian Dram"
ANG: "Netherlands Antillean Guilder"
ARS: "Argentine Peso"
AUD: "Australian Dollar"
}
```

And i want an array that exactly looks like this where first row is index 0 and secound row is 1 and so on. Blew you can see my attempts but somewhere it goes wrong and i get at index one the key and index two its property.

Javascript:

```
  Object.y = function (obj) {
  var yaxel = [];
  var y = 0, key;
  for (key in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) yaxel.push(key) && yaxel.push(obj[key]);
  }
  return yaxel;
  };

  var y = Object.y(jsonData["currencies"]);
  console.log(y); //this outputs the blew array
```

array:

```
0: "AED"
1: "United Arab Emirates Dirham"
2: "ALL"
3: "Albanian Lek"
4: "AMD"
5: "Armenian Dram"
6: "ANG"
7: "Netherlands Antillean Guilder"
8: "ARS"
9: "Argentine Peso"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use reduce for array of object.keys:

```
Object.y = function (obj) {
 return Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc,rec) => acc.concat(`${rec}: ${obj[rec]}`), [])
}
```

```js
let currencies = {

AED: "United Arab Emirates Dirham",
ALL: "Albanian Lek",
AMD: "Armenian Dram",
ANG: "Netherlands Antillean Guilder",
ARS: "Argentine Peso",
AUD: "Australian Dollar",
}

const func =  (obj) => {
 return Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc,rec) => acc.concat(`${rec}: ${obj[rec]}`), [])
}
 console.log(func(currencies))
```

Comment: this returns empty array, i console.logged the obj inside function and it logs the right object but the acc is empty array

Comment: I've modified function, both values can be added at once. Sorry, forgot to assign values back to array. I've tested current implementation and it seems working

Comment: @RezaAhmadi sorry, extra return statement. Added snippet

Answer (score 0):

```js
const currencies = {
  AED: "United Arab Emirates Dirham",
  ALL: "Albanian Lek",
  AMD: "Armenian Dram",
  ANG: "Netherlands Antillean Guilder",
  ARS: "Argentine Peso",
  AUD: "Australian Dollar"
}

console.log(Object.keys(currencies).map((item, i) => {
  return `${i}: '${item}: ${currencies[item]}'`
}))
```

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: No. It should be a normal array. And at index 0 instead of what you have written here it should be "0" : "AED : United Arab Emirates Dirham". The key here is 0 not AED

Comment: So ["0":"AED", "1": "ALL",... ] like this?

Comment: No. an array that looks like this: [0: "AED: United Arab Emirates Dirham"
1: "ALL: Albanian Lek"
2: "AMD: Armenian Dram"
3: "ANG: Netherlands Antillean Guilder", ...]

Comment: Where should the comma be? If I am right, it should look like  [0: "AED: United Arab Emirates Dirham" ,1: "ALL: Albanian Lek" ,2: "AMD: Armenian Dram", 3: "ANG: Netherlands Antillean Guilder", ...]

Comment: Check it ourt now

Answer (score 0):

```js
const currencies = {
  AED: "United Arab Emirates Dirham",
  ALL: "Albanian Lek",
  AMD: "Armenian Dram",
  ANG: "Netherlands Antillean Guilder",
  ARS: "Argentine Peso",
  AUD: "Australian Dollar"
}

console.log(Object.keys(currencies).map((item, i) => {
  return item;
}))
```

Answer (score -1):

I found it out by my own. i wanted to use it in html and instead of one increment in for loop i did i+=2 increment instead at final expression.

So it looks like this:

```
            for (var i = 0; i < y.length; i+=2) {
                document.getElementById('something').innerHTML += "<option>" + y[i] + " : " + y[i + 1] + "</option>";
            }
```